# Memory allocation of 4GB ignored in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to update the memory allocation limit of a Firebase Cloud Function to 4GB. I updated the memory value with the `runWith` parameter:

```js
functions.runWith({memory: "4GB"})
```

This, however, is being ignored and the deployed function does not have 4 GB of memory allocated.

If I try with 3GB, i get this error:

> Error: The only valid memory allocation values are: 128MB, 256MB, 512MB, 1GB, 2GB, 4GB

So it seems 4 GB is a valid value.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

It seems to work just fine if I use 2GB, 1GB... It only ignores the 4 GB value.

Comment: and what if you first delete this function and then add it back with new settings?

Comment: Have you checked this issue https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/807? They added PR make sure you have v3.12.0 as thats when they added the update. Also in their docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions) seems like they dont have 4gb option supported yet

Comment: @IvanChernykh, I did it and then it gets the default value 256 MB instead of the 4GB.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused, I saw the docs but as the console error response includes 4GB option I supposed that the 4GB option would be included and the docs outdated. I have firebase-functions dependency updated to v3.12.0 but I will take a look to the PR, thank you!

Comment: This seems to be an known issue, however I wasn't able to find an open issue for this, so I recommend you to open a new bug [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and reached out to Firebase Support to report the bug. According to Firebase Support, they acknowledge it's a bug and will release a fix in their next release.

In the time of reading, if the issue is not fixed this is the workaround:

1. Go the GCP console and select your project
2. select Cloud Functions from the menu on the left
3. Click "edit"
4. Expand the section "VARIABLES, NETWORKING AND ADVANCED SETTINGS"
5. Change the "memory allocated" field.
6. Click "Next" and then click on "Deploy"

EDIT: The fix has been released in [firebase-functions@3.13.1](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for reporting the bug and the solution :). Did they tell you the release version?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately they did not.

Comment: Great! Fix released. Thank you for including it ^^

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 July

> memory: amount of memory to allocate to the function, possible values are: '128MB', '256MB', '512MB', '1GB', '2GB', '4GB', and '8GB'.

```
functions.runWith({
    memory: '4GB',

}).firestore
```